# Customized R Graph with Different scales in X-axis

Tags: r, graph

I want to plot this customized Graph in R which has first decreasing scale on X-axis and than after a some gap, it again start with increasing scale.

Figure is attached below:[image]

Suppose this is a demo data set. First column "THETA" is the value of the parameter that is to be plotted on X-axis for two other columns "ALPH" and "BET" on Y-axis but with different scales for both.

```
      theta   alph    bet
 [1,]   0.1 0.9916 0.0002
 [2,]   0.2 0.8727 0.0292
 [3,]   0.3 0.6538 0.2083
 [4,]   0.4 0.4544 0.4755
 [5,]   0.5 0.3064 0.6554
 [6,]   0.6 0.2160 0.7822
 [7,]   0.7 0.1450 0.8535
 [8,]   0.8 0.1025 0.9004
 [9,]   0.9 0.0704 0.9294
[10,]   1.0 0.0497 0.9489
[11,]   1.1 0.0387 0.9673
[12,]   1.2 0.0274 0.9712
[13,]   1.3 0.0218 0.9814
[14,]   1.4 0.0148 0.9847
[15,]   1.5 0.0115 0.9868
[16,]   1.6 0.0085 0.9893
[17,]   1.7 0.0064 0.9920
[18,]   1.8 0.0052 0.9929
[19,]   1.9 0.0042 0.9952
[20,]   2.0 0.0045 0.9952
[21,]   2.1 0.0039 0.9978
[22,]   2.2 0.0023 0.9971
[23,]   2.3 0.0015 0.9988
```

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to freely position and designate values to axes. You need to adjust your data if it doesn't fit the canvas, it is unclear to me if it does in your example.

```
plot(type="n",0,0,xlim=c(0,20),ylim=c(0,15),xlab="",ylab="my y lab",axes=FALSE,cex.lab=0.5)
axis(side = 2,cex.axis=0.5)
add=9
pos=7
axis(side = 2,labels = c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3),at = c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3)+add ,pos = pos,cex.axis=0.5,line=1,las=2)
text(pos-1.5,add,"z-score",srt=90, cex=0.5)
add=11
pos=5
axis(side = 1,labels = c(9,8,7,6,5,4,3),at = c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3)+add ,pos = pos,cex.axis=0.5,line=1,las=1)
add=3.3
pos=1
axis(side = 1,labels = c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3),at = c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3)+add ,pos = pos,cex.axis=0.5,line=1,las=1)
```